# File upload and download facility on website through jsp

Tags: jsp

I want to make an website in jsp in which i can download a file and upload a file to the server.

plz help me

Answer (score 0):

You would need some servlets as well, to interact on the server side with your jsp. Here, take a look at [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478985.aspx#aspnet-jspmig-downloadinganduploading_topic2). You may find some techniques you need here.

Answer (score 0):

was also stuck on the same....found  a very helpful resource to do it.

Refer http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_file_uploading.htm

The link is great for getting started.